# Which OT era X-Wings had spirals on their laser cannons?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In one of the trailers for The Mandalorian: Season 2, we see two X-Wings flanking the *Razor Crest*. The one nearest the camera has a spiral on the upper left laser cannon (and a yellow nose cone...)

**What OT era X-Wings had spirals like this on their laser cannons?**

*FWIW - the only X-Wing I can find that also had a yellow nose cone is Wedge's Red-2 and his ship had a spiral, but on a different cannon (afaik)*

[image]

Comment: Not to negate finding an answer, since I'm curious as well, but the spiral is just a paint job, not a component. In Star Wars Rebels, paint was regularly changed on droids and ship for missions or to claim them for the team. It could easily be that the spirals here have no bearing on who the ship used to or currently belongs to.

Comment: certainly a possibility @Kadima - though, the X-Wings seem to be more akin to a permanent military assignment and seem to go along with a given pilot for their career (ie, Luke's X-Wing) but it's a good comment

Comment: I bet people are supposed to think it is Red 2 (Wedge) to get people speculating and watching ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

EDIT with whose X-Wings these are, Mandalorian Season 2 spoilers:

> **As seen in Episode 2, these are the X-Wings of Trapper Wolf and Carson Teva of the New Republic**

First I'm gonna say that I highly doubt it's characters or X-wings that we know - these X-wings flew in the battle of the first Death Star some 10 years before and only two made it out Red 5 and Red 2: Luke and Wedge.

Red 5 has the spiral on both Port upper cannon and starboard lower, but it doesn't have a yellow nose, and the depicted X-Wing lacks the stripe along the nose in front of the cockpit.

**Red 2 and Red 5 are the only fighters with the distinctive spiral cannons, with Red 5 having upper port (shown in [the image found here](http://www.nexus-models.com/red-5-build-2010.html) and posted below) and lower starboard, and Red 2 having upper starboard.**

The X-Wings depicted do not match the markings for either of these two, as the one with the spiral on the upper port has a yellow nose and no yellow stripe along the nose in front of the cockpit - a distinctive mark of Red 5. It's also not Red 2 unless it has a different cannon installed.

It's far more likely to me that these just happen to have similar markings as they are speculatively part of Red Squadron. We won't know more until the episode has aired.

[image: X Wing Models]